# The service installer does not remove the service on uninstall

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-services, installation, setup-project

Using Visual Studio 2010 I have created system service installer IndexingService (property ServiceName in installer) named Indexing Service (property ProductName in setup project).
Service installs and works properly but installer won't remove system service (and therefore won't reinstall it)
What should i look for?
UPDATE: I forgot to update custom action on uninstall

Comment: How did you configure the service installation? Are you using an install custom action? If so, did you configure an uninstall custom action which removes the service?

Comment: Yes, of course. I am followed kb816169 instructions and installation did work. After long time i am changed all names, added descriptions, assembly information in all subprojects / installers / setup project.

Comment: Did you update the custom actions to work with the new service information? Also, did you try creating a log to see if the custom action runs?

Comment: Project names were not changed (and installation work even now). So, i have only one custom action that does not require update (it do not have special properties). Now i am able to delete the service only using SC DELETE IndexingService.

Comment: And i can't realize that is wrong in installation log

Comment: Post the log somewhere so we can take a look.

Comment: Ok, you was right... I forgot to update the uninstall custom action. Problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i forgot to configure one of the custom actions properly.
Thank you, Cosmin Pirvu!